# How do I use Sprite Sheets in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Argh!!! I am new to this whole python thing and the only way I know how to make a "animation" is by using individual pictures (as in 1 pic per file). Well, I got a sprite sheet that is perfect for what I need, only problem is that it is a sprite sheet. I don't want to spend the time, cropping each individual sprite out.

More information, I am **new** to python and pygame. Just started learning the language back in August is a class that is moving very slowly...so if you could explain what you are doing so I can do it for future projects I would really appreciate it. I am also using Python 3.2, if that makes a difference because I am pretty sure there are some syntax differences between Python 2 and Python 3.

THANKS!!!! This will help me a lot.

Comment: there is a nice spritesheet class that is great imho(and easy to understand) ... http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet

Comment: Post some of your code that's giving you problems? Also some more explanation what you're trying to do would be good (personally, I've got absolutely no idea as to what a *sprite sheet* is).

Comment: In the future, you might want to try Google, or the documentation. Searching either Google or the pygame wiki for "pygame sprite sheet", or your entire question title, turns up the link Joran and I found, as the first hit. Doing that would avoid the need for you to write those two extra paragraphs. And Google can answer in 0.19 seconds instead of taking 3 minutes like a human. Plus, we may end up with your SO question beating the more useful wiki page for future searchers, slowing _everyone_ down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really isn't very hard to do… but the best sample code I found in a quick search is *also* a usable library that does the work for you: [`spritesheet`](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet), right from the pygame wiki.

So, you can start off by just using that. I'd give you an example tailored to your use case, but you haven't given us any idea what your code looks like or what you want to do, so I can't possibly give you anything better than is already on that page, so:

```
import spritesheet
...
ss = spritesheet.spritesheet('somespritesheet.png')
# Sprite is 16x16 pixels at location 0,0 in the file...
image = ss.image_at((0, 0, 16, 16))
images = []
# Load two images into an array, their transparent bit is (255, 255, 255)
images = ss.images_at((0, 0, 16, 16),(17, 0, 16,16), colorkey=(255, 255, 255))
…
```

Meanwhile, you can read the (very simple) code in that `spritesheet` class to understand how it works.

Comment: Sorry if this is a really dumb question, but do you know how to find out where a sprite in on a sprite sheet or do I just have to mess around with the values. Like do I have to find the values in GIMP or something?

Comment: The image parts in an animation sprite sheet should be of fixed size. All you have to do is divide the resolution of sheet according to the number of sprites in it. If there are too many sprites, just use a simple loop for parsing

Comment: sometimes you need to tweek it

Comment: @ZaidSaeed: For a sprite sheet where everything is the same size, it's easy: Just divide the size of the sheet by the number of sprites (in each direction). Just be aware that a few sprite sheets have spacing between the sprites—e.g., 8 16x16 sprites per row, 1-pixel border between sprites, that's 8*16+1*7=135, and if you just divide 135/8 you'll get 16.875, when you wanted 17.

Comment: @ZaidSaeed: For a sprite sheet with different-sized sprites, there's really no automated way to figure out the boundaries; you have to do it by eye, and write down the values yourself in GIMP. There are a few sprite sheets that have borders in a color not used anywhere else on the sheet, which in theory is automatable, but the code isn't too simple…