# How to fix 'Couldn't open C:\GAME\R1.png' in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to learn how to make a game using python and pygame, but I'm pretty new to this, so I can't understand the jargon that comes with the answers that are similar to my own question.

I'm following a video playlist on YouTube called Tech With Tim and I need to use some images for the character in the game, but the images simply won't load and keeps coming up with 'Couldn't open C:\GAME\R1.png'.

They're already in the same folder why is what makes this so confusing. All the images are also named correctly to the best of my understanding (i.e. they all have the names used in the code below:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R1.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R2.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R4.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R5.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R7.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R8.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L1.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L2.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L4.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L5.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L7.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L8.png'), pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\Bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('C:\GAME\standing.png')

x = 50
y = 425
width = 64
height = 64
vel = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount

    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkCount = 0

    pygame.display.update()


run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - vel - width:
        x += vel
        left = False
        right = True

    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        walkCount = 0

    if not (isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            left = False
            right = False
            walkCount = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

I expect to see the game load and work, but instead, the error 'Couldn't open C:\GAME\R1.png' comes up.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Not sure this might be the problem in this particular instance. But try `C:\\GAME\\R1.png` instead. Seeing as Python will escape the backslashes. But according to the error message this might not be the only issue, still worth making sure. Or use a raw string without parsing: `r'C:\GAME\R1.png'`

Comment: Also, considering using [Sprite sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109487/how-do-i-use-sprite-sheets-in-pygame) instead of arrays with pre-loaded images :)

Comment: Well, *is* there a file named R1.png in the GAME folder of your hard drive's root directory?  A file by that name anywhere else is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that is the good path to your file.
Also, you should use '/' instead of '\'. Your path should be : 'C:/GAME/R1.png'